# Why PHP visibility like private property can still be modified and accessed?

Tags: php

I am thinking why php added visibility such as private, protected, and public when you can still access it using arrow functions? Please see code below

**Code**

```
<?php

class Foo
{
  private $secret = 'foo';
}

$foo = new Foo();

(fn() => $this->secret = 'bar')->call($foo);

echo (fn() => $this->secret)->call($foo);
```

**Output**

> bar

[PHP Code Snippet](https://onecompiler.com/php/3ycnkbn8z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is working as expected because the closure you are using is bounded to the current object's class scope you pass   in the first parameter of `call` method.

So naturally, all private, protected, public members of the current class will be accessible.

Below, is a demonstration to prove this when we try to access private property of a parent class private variable, yet accessing and modifying our own private member variable works just fine.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php


class Bar{
  private static $barSecret = 'bar';
}

class Foo extends Bar{
  private $fooSecret = 'foo';
  
  public function getFooSecret(){
    return $this->fooSecret;
  }
  
  public function printBarSecret(){
    echo parent::$barSecret;
  }
}

$foo = new Foo();

(fn() => $this->fooSecret .= " callback append")->call($foo);

echo $foo->getFooSecret();

(fn() => $this->printBarSecret())->call($foo);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/55d12)

Comment: doesn't it destroy the use of visibility?

Comment: Also, why I can access the private property when Im using arrow function? But when I try to access it like `(new Foo())->secret`, it will throw an error

Comment: @Jie It doesn't destroy any visibility since it is binded to the class scope. It is very useful when you are working with complex applications or frameworks where certain actions need to be taken only during run time and so they don't qualify to be a class method. `(new Foo())->secret` is outside of the class scope, hence the error.

Comment: @Jie Did my answer make sense?

Comment: Binded meaning you can access any private and protected properties and methods when you bind a class to the `call()` function?

Comment: @Jie Yes but only of the class whose object you passed in.

Comment: Got it bro, crystal clear

Answer (score 0):

As you know private properties are not inherited so you are not really accessing `private` variable itself, so **what really happening here is that when you are trying to access your `private` property from the class object, `PHP` can't find it So it's dynamically creating new public one for you**.

So use `Protected` properties instead because they **are inherited** and that's why you **can't access them from other parts of the code**.

checkout the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) for more information.

Comment: I can still access the property even if I changed it to `protected`.

Comment: you are not really accessing it you are making a function to create one for you, try this code `<?php

class Foo
{
  protected $secret = 'foo';
}

$foo = new Foo();
echo ($foo->secret);`

Comment: And `Protected` variable can be accessed inside the child class. but in your case, it is not inside the child's class. and You can access the protected variable by making the `getter` function too.

Comment: There is no dynamically created property; there are several ways to access private properties outside a php class

Comment: @yolenoyer What I am saying is that, @jie  is not accessing the variable itself, PHP just created one for him because he try to set a value for one, if you just try to print the value without setting anything, you will see the error, here is the example code - `<?php

class Foo
{
  private $secret = 'foo';
}

$foo = new Foo();

(fn() => $this->secret = 'bar')->call($foo);

echo ($foo->secret);`

Comment: You're not forced to set any value to access the private prop outside the class, eg `<?php class Foo { private $secret = 'foo'; } $foo = new Foo(); (function() { echo $this->secret; })->call($foo);`

Comment: To be more explicit, you can even return the value `echo (fn() => $this->secret)->call($foo);`

Comment: Wait what!!, when I try to use a private variable directly with an object, it shows an error, see `<?php class Foo {
  private $secret = 'foo'; 
  
} 
$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->secret; `  but with function, I am able to do it, wow!! I did not know that, thank you for sharing @yolenoyer . this was something interesting.